# Windows cannot automatically detect network proxy settings

Tags: windows-7

Using Windows 7 lost my connection to the internet. Received notice, Windows could not automatically detect this network's proxy settings. How do I fix?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: See if you can reset the network:   Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator
(1) netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt
(2) ipconfig /flushdns
(3) restart the computer

Comment: Do you have a proxy, or have you just simply lost connectivity to the internet? Try to reboot the router and then the computer.